# Looking for a procurement software

Tags: web-apps

My company is at a point where we need to keep track of our bills. In other words, we are looking for a software (preferably web based) application that would let us track and update the status of the bills for our projects, from the time we get a price quote from a vendor, to when the purchase order is generated and the invoice is paid. My preference is an open source product if there is any. Can anyone recommend such a software package or application?

We are looking for something basic. Right now we want to

- track and update the status of the bills for our projects
- attach pdf copies of the paper work to the record
- track the person who last updated the record
- create reports by current status

I don't need "active monitoring" (i.e. the software alerting you on deadlines etc.), but rather "passive tracking" (reports generated only on demand, or at scheduled intervals, regardless of the "status").
The back-end technologies (PHP, MySQL) does not matter. Our preference is to

- host in house if setting up and maintaining is not too complicated. Otherwise we can do a cloud based app.
- open source product if there is any